# Only paint the paint mask selected faces in vertex paint

Tags: vertex-colors, vertex-paint, vertex-paint-mode

[image]

I'm using the latest blender stable build: 3.5, in past versions it worked fine to just activate paint mask, and it only painted the selected face. Now, it suddenly stopped working with the latest version.

I don't want the white color in this case to " bleed down " but just the top face to be white. Did I forget a setting? Can you please help me to fix this?

Comment: it still works for me, are you sure that you're doing it correctly?

Comment: @moonboots I'm doing every step I also did before with older versions

Comment: @moonboots What are the steps you are doing it with? Normally, it worked like that:
Add Color attribute, connect color attribute node with the color attribute name to the principled bsdf node in the shading editor, go to edit mode, select the face, go to vertex paint mode, activate face mask, set material view, set colors and such, start drawing.
Now, it still has the bleeding effect.